# How to get url from link

Tags: php

I'm using Visual Composer in Wordpress. I have created own custom element.
Now I'm trying to figure out how to get url from link.
If I print {$a['link']} I get url and title:

> url:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com|title:url_title|

This should be pretty easy(?) but just could not figure it out.

```
 return "<div class='icon_text_box'>
 <a href='{$a['link']}'>
   <div class='icon_image'><img src='$image_url' alt='icon' / ></div>
   <div class='icon_text'>{$a['text_heading']}</div>
 </a>
 </div>";
```

[Here is whole element](http://pastie.org/10480543)

Comment: use urldecode() ans see if you are getting correct url.

Comment: Why do you print $link instead of $a['link'] ?

Comment: @lonut If I print $link it outputs Array

Comment: Of course it prints Array, because $link is an array. You should print $a['link'] to get the link. I don't understand what is that hard...

Comment: Well.. As I said on my post if I print $a['link'] it outputs this: url:http%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com|title:url_title|

Comment: No. On your question you said $link.